# .NET Single Line Logging (ala Trace.Write/WriteLine) using Instrumentation.Logging

Tags: .net, logging, trace, instrumentation

My question is whether it is possible to get line/multiline (very unsure of correct term for this) behaviour of the Trace.Write and Trace.WriteLine methods but using the Microsoft Instrumentation Logging framework in .NET 2.0.

Desired Output

```
Hello World!
Oh Hai.
```

What I Currently Have

```
Trace.Write("Hello ");
Trace.WriteLine("World!");
Trace.Write("Oh Hai.");
```

I would prefer to use instrumentation to log rather than writing to a log file using Debug.Trace.

EDIT: By Instrumentation Logging I mean using a 'loggingConfiguration' block in my App.config and writing Log Entries using using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write(LogEntry logEntry);

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0 for example.

Ta,
KnownColor

Comment: Please clarify what "microsoft instrumentation logging" you are referring to.

Comment: Where is this "loggingConfiguration" block from? Enterprise Library? What version? Somewhere else? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending **Environment.NewLine** in your logging statements when needed?

Comment: This is the default behaviour of it, it always writes entries onto a new line, what I would like is to be able to write an entry and (optionally) have it write the next entry after the previous on the same line.